# Django form doesn't save value in multiple choice fields

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm using Django's ModelForm and for no reason my form doesn't save the value of multiple choice fields. This is my `models.py`:

```
class CaptureVersion(models.Model):
    id_capture = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50, verbose_name="Nom Disseny")
    int_reference_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='IRN')
    capture_version_id_provider = models.ForeignKey(Provider, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='id_provider', verbose_name='Proveïdor')
    associated_register = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Registre associat')
    start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Data Alta')
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Data Baixa')
    target_size = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Regions diana (Mb)')
    probe_size = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Sondes (Mb)')
    sections = models.ManyToManyField(Section, blank=True, verbose_name="Secció")
    responsibles = models.ManyToManyField(Responsible, blank=True, verbose_name="Responsable/s")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['start_date']
        db_table = 'capture_version'
```

And my `forms.py`:

```py
class FormulariCaptura(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CaptureVersion
        fields = ("name", "int_reference_number", "capture_version_id_provider", "associated_register", "start_date", 
        "end_date", "target_size", "probe_size", "sections", "responsibles",)
```

The problem are the fields `sections` and `responsibles` which are foreign keys. When I select one of the values of the dropdown list in the form, there's no problem and the entry is saved with no apparent errors but the value in the table for that field is `-`. But if I do it in the admin, it works or if I edit the entry with `UpdateView`.

This worked yesterday and I didn't change anything...

My `views.py`:

```
def capture_form(request):

   formulari_captura=FormulariCaptura()

   if request.method=="POST":

      formulari_captura=FormulariCaptura(request.POST or None)

      if formulari_captura.is_valid():

        feedback = formulari_captura.save(commit=False)
        capture = CaptureVersion.objects.all()
        feedback.capture = capture
        feedback.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Kit de captura enregistrat correctament!')        

    return render(request, "captureVersion/formulari_captura.html", {'formulari':formulari_captura})
```

My `form.html`:

```
<div class="formMostra">

{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
    <p style="margin: 20px;" {% if message.tags %} class=" {{ message.tags }} " {% endif %}> {{ message }} </p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

<form action="" method="POST" style="text-align: justify;">
    {% csrf_token %}
   <table style="margin: 20px;">{{formulari.as_table}}</table>
   <input type="submit" value="Afegir" style="width: 100px; margin: 20px; margin-right: 0px;" class="btn btn-primary">
   <input onclick="location.href='/sample/'" value="Cancel·lar" style="width: 100px; margin: 20px; margin-left: 0px;" class="btn btn-light">
</form>
```

Comment: I'm not sure but what is `feedback.capture = capture` for? `CaptureVersion` has no `capture` field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the [**`docs`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method):

> Calling save_m2m() is only required if you use save(commit=False). When you use a save() on a form, all data – including many-to-many data – is saved without the need for any additional method calls.

If you use `save(commit=False)`, you have to call `save_m2m()` after, so:

```
feedback = formulari_captura.save(commit=False)
feedback.save()
formulari_captura.save_m2m()
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now! But it's odd since it worked before without this command... Is there any explanation?

Comment: Hmm not sure, but if you used just `formulari_captura.save()` without `commit=False` it would work as well

Answer (score 0):

In the file 'form.html' you need to put the attribute 'action'.

-> The 'action' attribute tells the form where to send the data. Without that information nothing happens ...

You should put something like:

```
<form action="{% url 'test_url' %}" method="POST">
```